# Is there a way to execute a specific service early in angular?

Tags: angular, user-interface, service, loading

Actually taking a new project in Angular, found a problem when i try to load a header & a menu in the app.component file. It seems they don't load completely or they don't communicate with the needed service. A function is checking if the user is allow to see some interface buttons, but it doesn't work without a reload (yes, after the page reload it works). Don't understand what is failing.

Tried to set the components in the entry components array but doesn't work.

Function to check permissions

```
isAllow (action) {
        let checked = false;
        if( localStorage.getItem ('allow')){
            let stored = JSON.parse(atob(localStorage.getItem('allow')))['permissions'];
            if(stored.includes(action))checked=true;
        }
        return checked;
    }
```

how the components are called in my app.component

```
<app-header></app-header>

<div id="main" class="grey lighten-4">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
        <app-alert></app-alert>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <app-menu></app-menu>
    </div>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

```
login (username: string, password: string) {
       return this.http.post<any>(Config.apiUrl + '/oauth',  { grant_type: 'password', username: username, password: password, client_id: username }, httpOptions)
        .pipe(map((res:any) => {
            if (res && res.access_token) {
                localStorage.setItem('currentAuth', btoa(JSON.stringify(res)));
                var user:any = {"username":username};
                localStorage.setItem('user', btoa(JSON.stringify(user)));
                this.currentToken = res.access_token;

                    this.user.getAccountById(res.account_id).subscribe(e=>{

                        localStorage.removeItem('allow');
                        localStorage.setItem('allow',btoa(JSON.stringify({'id':res.account_id,'permissions':(e['type']==1?['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']:(e['levels']!=null?e['levels']:['0'])),'type':e['type'],'id_client':e['id_client']})));
                        this.loggedIn.next(true);
                        this.router.navigate(['']);
                    })
            }
        }));
    }
```

I expect the menu and the header to successfully load my interface buttons on the first load... Feel free to ask me more about this (Sorry for my english)

Comment: I suppose you are calling your function in `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: @Alencruser have you use service in  constructor like this `constructor(private MS: MyService) {}` in AppComponent

Comment: Have a look at the APP_INITIALIZER injection token. Could be what you are looking for

Comment: Hey check my answer if it would resolve your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55741492/568627

Comment: Hum.. I tried the APP_initializer thing, it could solve my problem but it injects a service, waiting for a service function , my problem is that the service function is called by a component and can only be after a log in.

Comment: i tried promise but didn't work, tried with APP_INITIALIZER but i need the login and pass to launch the function, here is the function i forgot to paste since i thought the problem was on the app.component.html side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve the problem after some time on anothers component.
I made properties in my service with type BehaviorSubject.
Then in the components i need :
-I assign the service properties values to the component properties
-In the html i let the ngIf="property".
 Don't know if there is a better way but didn't find another one, thanks all for the help btw.